# Installing a bundled set of multiple apps automatically and silently

Tags: windows, installer, windows-installer, bundle

When I install Windows, I like to deploy a set of the same apps (for example, Firefox, Chrome, Trillian, 7-Zip, etc.). I'd prefer to have a way of doing it all in one sitting, and I seem to remember there being a way of bundling all the installers. I was able to find two, though neither of them look like what I was thinking of.

Update: Adding everyone's suggestions:

- InstallPad (uses editable XML list, doesn't work very well...)
- WPKG
- Allmyapps (Windows and Linux)
- Ninite
- TGUP (The Great Unattended Project)
- INEO (Just a batch file)
- Almeza MultiSet
- WPIW
- Unattended/nLite (network requirements)
- AppSnap

Can anyone recommend other ways of running a whole set of installers at once? Thanks!

(Will add links when I get enough points)

Comment: Now anyone can help adding in links :-)

Answer (score 5):

There's a tool called [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) which does precisely that for a select few applications. Sadly, Trillian hasn't been added to their list of installable applications, but it's always saved me a fair amount of time after reformats for 95% of what I make use of.

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of! Thanks Dylan. I'll compare them and see how they rate.

Answer (score 1):

I use a batch file, which includes Firefox and 7-zip. Both of these installers can be run silently from the command line:

> "Firefox Setup 3.6.3.exe" -ms
>
> 7z465.exe /S

will silently install them (very quickly!).

You could look into whether the other programs you use have similar options.